# How do I run `wsl --update --web-download` behind a corporate proxy?

Tags: proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

When I run this command in Windows PowerShell I get an error:

```
>>  wsl --update --web-download
Proxy authentication required (407).
```

I've tried setting `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` variables with my proxy server, username, and password, and I get the same result.

My background is more in linux than windows, so I might be missing some standard way to do this.

Comment: A few other context notes: 

1. `wsl --update` (without `web-download`) fails with an error `0x8024500c` I am guessing because the company disables the windows store, which I think is the default download location. Thta is why I'm trying the `--web-download` flag.

2. I am trying to get WSL2 for use with docker.

Comment: I've found it hard to search for help with proxy in the context of the `wsl` command itself. Most that pop up questions seem to involve the proxy from within ubuntu or similar.